# Entity Framework database first but don't want to create models automatically?

Tags: entity-framework

I am following a book on asp.net mvc written by Adam Freeman he used a different approach through out the book he created the database first but didn't let Entity Framework create models for him due to certain reasons.

I liked his approach, it simplified a lot of things. Now my problem is in his book he created a single table for demo purpose and I want to use this approach for multiple tables but don't know how to communicate between tables in that case do I have to create navigational properties in each model and foreign keys as well or its not necessary?

Comment: yes it is necessarry, but simple. Search for *code fisrt with existing database*

Comment: Do it cause migration related problems someone told me that ?

Comment: I am not using migration, but as far as I know, there should not be any problems

Comment: Your question is too broad; EF itself is a bit topic. Please read a book or watch a training video about EF.